# ASP.NET MVC Html.RenderAction method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I try to use the method something like this:

```
<%Html.RenderAction<NavigatorController>(n => n.Menu());%>
```

but got an exception "A public action method 'Menu' could not be found on controller 'WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController'. Why compiler try to find it in ProductsController, if I specify NavigatorController for this purposes?
Code in my NavigatorController  very simple:

```
namespace WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class NavigatorController : Controller
    {
        public string Menu()
        {
            return "NavigatorController here";
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I use RenderAction from ASP.NET MVC Features library.

I resolved this issue. As @jfar mentioned error was something else, error was in my custom controller factory module, that I wrote using Castle.Windsor library, I tried to implement inversion of control describing in Steven Sanderson book (Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework). So, my method that register all Controller types was:

```
    _container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));
                IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes = from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                                    where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                                                    select type;

container.Register(Component.For(controllerTypes).LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));
```

After reading some article I replace it by this:

```
_container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .BasedOn<Controller>()
                .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient.Named(c.Implementation.Name.ToLower())));
```

and all work fine now

Comment: Can you post your route configuration please?  This sounds like the issue might be in there.

Comment: you can replace `AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` with `AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()` See the documentation http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following statement in your view.

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Navigator"); %>
```

Comment: I use this statement before I become use Html.RenderAction<NavigatorController>, but with Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Navigator"); effect is the same

Comment: @Kai i am using asp.net mvc 2, and its working here. what is your mvc version?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC 1 with ASP.NET MVC Features library, I added it as reference to my project to use RenderAction method

Answer (score 1):

This error must be happening someplace else.

```
<%Html.RenderAction<NavigatorController>(n => n.Menu());%>
```

This code would always use the NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Like jfar said:

> This error must be happening someplace else.

Check your routes.

My guess is you modified your routes, and it's always picking the one for the ProductsController.